# use custom grids in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, grids-graticules, wmts

is there a way to use/transform from the custom grid in this [WMTS Capabilities](https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wmts_geosn_dop-rgb/guest?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMTS) to the osm grid to use the wmts with leaflet ?

I'm using the leaflet-tilelayer-wmts plugin and i cannot display any tile from the wmts linked above due to other tilenames and grid. Both my map and my requests are in EPSG:3857.

```
var ortho = L.tileLayer.wmts('https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wmts_geosn_dop-rgb/guest?', {
    layer: 'sn_dop_020',
    style: 'default',
    format: "image/png",
    tilematrixSet: 'grid_3857',

});
```

Comment: What I can see inside [the XML file](https://geodienste.sachsen.de/wmts_geosn_dop-rgb/guest?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMTS), that it supports EPSG:31468, EPSG:25833, EPSG:4326 and the grid that you need EPSG:3857. I would probably refer you to this article [Using Leaflet with WMTS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466634/using-leaflet-with-wmts-server).

Comment: Im already using this leaflet plugin but its not creating the correct queries --> wrong zoom level, tilerow and tilecolumn